# How to Filter Restructured Data in Polymer (dom-repeat)

Tags: arrays, filter, polymer, polymer-2.x, dom-repeat

I am trying to filter an array that is being reindexed on-the-fly.

I would like to have a single input field that matches strings on multiple properties.

```
<paper-input value="{{val}}" placeholder="Filter Cards"></paper-input>

<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[restructure(data)]]" initial-count="2" filter="{{filter(val, data)}}">
  <card-items data="[[item]]" items="[[item.items]]" links="false"></card-items>
</template>
```

...

This function restructures the data to be formatted for a card layout.

```
returnInvoices(data) {
  let newData = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    let noOrder = data[i].noOrder;
    if (!newData[noOrder]) {
      newData[noOrder] = {
        idMaster: data[i].idMaster,
        itemId: data[i].itemId,
        description: data[i].description,
        noOrder: noOrder,
        items: []
      };
    }
    newData[noOrder].items.push('{' +
      '"idMaster":"' + data[i].idMaster + '",' +
      '"itemId":"' + data[i].itemId + '"}');
  }
  return newData.filter(val => val).sort((a, b) => {return b.noInvoice - a.noInvoice}) // reindex array
}
```

I would like this function to return objects in the array whom have properties that match a string.

```
filter(val, data) {
  if (!val) return null;
    else {
      val = val.toLowerCase();
      // not sure what to do here
      // would like to filter on all object properties (from data)
    return data[0];
  }
}
```

...

Example

`if(val == 1) return data[0] & data[1];`

`if(val == 'Item') return data[0] & data[2];`

For data array

```
let data = [
  {"itemId": "1", "description": "Nice Item", "noOrder": 123},
  {"itemId": "2", "description": "Good Product", "noOrder": 123},
  {"itemId": "3", "description": "Fine Item", "noOrder": 444}
}
```

...

**How can I filter strings on all 3 properties?**

**How can I use the filter as an intermediate function to the restructuring?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for dom-repeat's [filter property](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/api/elements/Polymer.DomRepeat#property-filter) includes following statements:

> The function should match the sort function passed to Array.filter. Using a filter function has no effect on the underlying items array.

And the Array.filter is [documented](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) as

> Function is a predicate, to test each element of the array. Return true to keep the element, false otherwise.

So from your filter func just return `true` if any of the properties matches input and `false` otherwise, something like

```
filter(item) {
  let val = this.val;
  // if the filter is empty show everything
  if (!val) return true;
  // otherwise see is there a match
  val = val.toLowerCase();
  return // for the "description" use "contains" logic
         (item.description.toLowerCase().includes(val)) ||
         // for the "noOrder" use "starting" logic
         (item.noOrder.toString().indexOf(val) == 0)
       // add matching conditions here ...
}
```

Now to trigger the filtering you must observe the properties which trigger filtering, ie your html would be like

```
<paper-input value="{{val}}" placeholder="Filter Cards"></paper-input>

<template is="dom-repeat" filter="[[filter]]" observe="val" items="[[restructure(data)]]" initial-count="2">
  <card-items data="[[item]]" items="[[item.items]]" links="false"></card-items>
</template>
```

BTW why do you push items into newData as strings? Why not as objects, ie

```
newData[noOrder].items.push({
  idMaster: data[i].idMaster,
  itemId: data[i].itemId
});
```

and I think you can lose the `newData.filter(val => val)` step...

Comment: Thank you for the thorough feedback! I'm not sure why the data was being pushed as strings, with your suggestion I am seeing a great performance boost!

Comment: "The function should match the sort function passed to Array.filter. Using a filter function has no effect on the underlying items array."  While this may be the case, does it mean that the filter is acting on `restructure(data)` or `data` itself?

Comment: Also, when observing `val` inside the `dom-repeat` the `filter` function seems to be fired every time a node is added to the DOM, which is very expensive for large arrays.  Would it not be better to observe an `on-change` event in the `paper-input` to maximize performance?

Comment: When running your suggested code `this.val` is returning `undefined` even when there is input in the `paper-input`, and therefore the filter is only returning `true` (the entire array).

Comment: Try to define `val` as a property of your component (ie in `get properties()`) or at least init it in `ready` method - hopefully this fixes the problem it not being observed/it's value not changing. Also make sure that the input is really bint to it, not to some other property...

Comment: OK.  I got a modified version of this working, but am still trying to figure out what you are doing with `(item.noOrder.toString().indexOf(val) == 0)`.

Comment: As the comment in the code explains it should check wether the "noOrder" starts with the "val" - `item.noOrder.toString()` converts it to string and then `indexOf(val)` returns the index at which the `val` appears in it. If there is no match then return value is `-1`, if the string starts with val then the returned value is zero, hece the `...==0` check. You could use `item.noOrder.toString().startsWith(val)` too.

Comment: Ah, I see... subtle. Thank you for the help!!